# Matching CheckListBox to RNG Values

Tags: vb.net

I am making a Lottery Program with a list of 99 checkboxes in a checklistbox. Then I am generating 5 random, unique numbers into a label. Would it be best for me to use a nested If statement to detect if any of my selected numbers match any of the generated numbers, or would something else be better? This is what I am using that isn't working.

```
Dim Matched As Integer = 0
    If PickedNumbers.Contains(value) Then Matched += 1
```

value contains the random numbers, and PickedNumbers are my selected numbers from the checklistbox.

UPDATE:

```
For Each n As Int32 In WinMatches
        WinningNumbers.Text = ("We matched on:" & " " & n & "!")
    Next
```

I can only get this to return 1 matched number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the label for anything other than displaying the winning numbers, especially since it wont be atomic if you glued all the winners into one string (as per your last question).  The `CheckedItems` collection will have the data, but as text, so you need to convert them to integer to compare:

```
Dim winners = Enumerable.Range(1, 99).OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next()).Take(5).ToArray

lblWinners.Text = String.Join(", ", winners)

Dim pick As Int32
Dim Matches As Int32
For n As Int32 = 0 To clbPicks.CheckedItems.Count - 1

    pick = Convert.ToInt32(clbPicks.CheckedItems(n))
    If (winners.Contains(pick)) Then
        Matches += 1
    End If

Next
```

---

If you like one-line linqy things:

```
Dim WinMatches = clbPicks.CheckedItems.Cast(Of String).
                   Where(Function(m) winners.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(m))).
                   ToArray()

Dim winValues = Array.ConvertAll(WinMatches, Function(i) Convert.ToInt32(i))
```

This will also give you *which* items/selections matched in `WinMatches` (albeit as string). The next line converts them to integer values.  Result:

```
For Each n As Int32 In WinMatches
    Console.WriteLine("Winner-Winner, Chicken Dinner on {0}", n)
Next
```

> Winner-Winner, Chicken Dinner on 7
>   Winner-Winner, Chicken Dinner on 18
>   Winner-Winner, Chicken Dinner on 40

Comment: Haven't been having any luck with this. I can only get it to return 1 matched number even if I select every checkbox. I changed the last part on it to make it work in a textbox.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. I need to put an &= instead of just .text =

Comment: The output window is an invaluable way to test that kind of thing for debugging: `Console.WriteLine("....")` upvote it if it helped. `lblWinners.Text = String.Join(", ", winners)` as shown in the answer will also work

Comment: I got you. Now the last thing I have to do is find a way to collect how many times a now was selected and how many times an rng number appeared when I click my Exit button.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `For Each` statement.

**Example**

This would look at every checkbox and check to see if it is checked, if it is "do something". You could put each checkbox value in its Text property then use that to work out what value has been selected.

```
Dim cControl As Control
        For Each cControl InMe.Controls
            If (TypeOf cControl Is CheckBox) Then
              If cControl.Checked = True Then
              value += cControl.Text
              End If

            End If
        Next cControl
```

Comment: I am using a CheckListBox though with 99 checkboxes, so I can't add a value. All values are in the Collection of items.

Comment: Use the Text property then.

Comment: Use this.. value += cControl.Text